# Random Teleport Character issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

I'm starting to take my first steps on unity and I'm trying to make a simple 2d game. I would like to create a teleport within the map. When my character comes into contact with a point he would be able to teleport between the various points on the map randomly as if it were a portal.

I have managed to insert a list with the points where it can move and with the Random function, I can move it. The problem is that the random function also calls the point where my character already is and therefore does not move.

This is what I would like to do: If I have three points A B C my character enters point A and can move to points B and C. If he goes to point B he can move to A and C and so on.

Now my character if he enters point A moves randomly to A B C.

How can I go about fixing it?

```
public class Transport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> Portal = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject Player;

    public void changePortal()
    {
        int aCaso = Random.Range(0, Portal.Count);

        Player.transform.position = new Vector2(Portal[aCaso].transform.position.x, Portal[aCaso].transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

this is the piece there code where the error appears

```
public prova ipa = null;

void Teleport()
{
       if ((CATTURA.phase == InputActionPhase.Performed) && (contatto == true))
       {

            if (ipa != null)
            {
                ipa.changePortal(); ***this is the code for teleporting 
    
        *** error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds
        to the required formal parameter 'sourcePortal' of
            'prova.changePortal(GameObject)’***
       
        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your line:

```
int aCaso = Random.Range(0, Portal.Count);
```

`0` to `Portal.Count` will always include all portals.

**The issue is that the pool of portals you can teleport to (target) still includes the portal you entered (origin).**

You may create a new list of portals that removes the source portal as such:

```
// Pass the origin portal (where your player enters)
public void changePortal(GameObject sourcePortal)
{
    // create a new list where sourcePortal is excluded
    var possibleTargets = Portal.Where(o => o != source).ToList(); 

    // random index from new list
    int aCaso = Random.Range(0, possibleTargets .Count);

    // use the random index to get target portal
    Player.transform.position = new Vector2(possibleTargets [aCaso].transform.position.x, possibleTargets [aCaso].transform.position.y);
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure I would mention that you need `using System.Linq;` in your script

Comment: thanks for the answer, but now i have another little problem, this script i posted was called by the function in the script character and when I pressed the Space key it teleported. Now he gives me this error. 

*** error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sourcePortal' of 'prova.changePortal(GameObject)’***

Excuse the ignorance but as I said I'm a beginner. Thanks

Comment: Hi, how do you currently call the function "changePortal" now? And do you have a reference to the portal your player is going into?

Comment: I'm trying to send you the piece of code but here besides the comment I don't know how to do it

Comment: I inserted it in the initial post

Comment: It looks like a third-party library, but anyway, what you'll need is a way to get the GameObject instance of the portal your player is entering. Do you have a way of doing that?

Comment: how could I do?

Comment: From your code, looks like something is setting your "contatto" variable to true, that's probably where you're gonna find the point of contact of your player to the portal.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you have this map set up, but you could have that random teleport feature transform your position using an array. Try to create an array for each teleportation pad, and with that do not include the current point. That may prevent teleporting to the same place or try to set a minimum teleportation distance, so that it searches for pads outside of that range.

I would look here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/589808/choose-random-gameobject-from-array.html

In this case they use spawn points, but I am sure you could use it for teleportation with your current code as well.